# List to JSON with JsonSerializer.Serializer returns null

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a class named `clsTest` which is defined as:

```
public class clsTest
{
    public string Name;
    public string Family;
    public int Age;
}
```

I have another class named `clsMain` which is Serializing three instances of `clsTest` class to JSON as:

```
public class clsMain
{
    public string mtdMain()
    {
        clsTest ct1_a = new clsTest();
        clsTest ct1_b = new clsTest();
        clsTest ct1_c = new clsTest();

        ct1_a.Name = "Satoshi";
        ct1_a.Family = "Nakamato";

        ct1_b.Name = "Charles";
        ct1_b.Family = "Hoskinson";
        ct1_b.Age = 33;

        ct1_c.Name = "AmirAli";
        ct1_c.Family = "Sam";
        ct1_c.Age = 25;

        List<clsTest> lst = new List<clsTest>();
        lst.Add(ct1_a);
        lst.Add(ct1_b);
        lst.Add(ct1_c);

        JsonSerializerOptions option = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        option.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        option.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));

        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(lst, option);
    }
}
```

When I debug the project my list is full as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

But at the end `return JsonSerializer.Serialize(lst, option);` serialize as below:

[image]

I couldn't find the problem, any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use properties instead of fields, like so:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```